# What is the best way to make every instance of a class know about one particular instance of another class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, aggregation

Thanks in advance for your help, somewhat of a hobbyist and trying to do my first big project using OOP.

I have four classes. Three of the classes always need to know about one particular instance of the other class.

I thought inheritance was the solution to my problem but quickly realised it wasn't - I think aggregation is more appropriate? Can anybody let me know if this is the most appropriate way to implement this?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, some_data):
        self.data = some_data

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo_instance):
        self.foo = foo_instance

class Fizz:
    def __init__(self, foo_instance):
        self.foo = foo_instance

class Wizz:
    def __init__(self, foo_instance):
        self.foo = foo_instance

foo = Foo("foobar")
bar = Bar(foo)
fizz = Fizz(foo)
wizz = Wizz(foo)
```

Or should I be defining the Bar, Fizz and Wizz classes inside the Foo class?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. A member indicates a **has a** relationship. So does `Foo` have a `Bar` or does `Bar` have a `Foo`?

For example, does a `Pet` have an owner (`Person`) or does a `Person` have a `Pet`? It comes down to what you will have to do: do you have to know who the owner of a `Pet` is or do you want to know what `Pet` a `Person` owns.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Every ``Bar``, ``Fizz`` and ``Wizz`` needs to know the one ``Foo`` they all belong to. A ``Foo`` has multiple ``Bar``s, ``Fizz``es, ``Wizz``es, but they all can exist independently from the ``Foo`` - (I think)